# Angular 14's FormGroup.get() is always possibly null. How do I make it non-nullable?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, formgroups, angular14

Angular 14 introduced typed forms, which are amazing, but I'm struggling with a specific part of it: `FormGroup.get(name)` now appears to always return `AbstractControl | null`. How can I get it to be non-nullable?

Let's take a look at this FormGroup:

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  first: new FormControl('John'),
  last: new FormControl('Smith'),
});
```

When I access one of these controls via `form.controls.first`, the FormControl is known to exist and I have no issues accessing its value trivially:

[image]

However, when I use `form.get('first')`, the return value is always possibly null, adding a layer of complication I have to account for:

[image]

Now, Angular's FormControls are being more careful around `FormControl.reset()`, so [their values can always be `null`](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#nullability) unless you set `{ nonNullable: true }`, like this:

```
new FormControl('John', { nonNullable: true });
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a corresponding explanation for why `FormGroup.get()` always returns a possibly-null value, and there doesn't seem to be any kind of `nonNullable: true` I can specify for FormGroups to ask it to guarantee the FormControl I request will be present. The difference between `form.get('first')` vs `form.controls.first` in terms of nullability is baffling to me.

**What should I be doing with my FormGroups to ensure `form.get(name)` is non-nullable?**

I understand I can use casts (`form.get('first') as FormControl<string>`) or non-null asserts (`form.get('first')!`) but those seem like they might be workarounds for a more core change I should be making in how I'm accessing or creating my forms.

Comment: You can use `form.controls.someControl` instead of `form.get('someControl')` in case the name is known at compile time.